# how to get ng-template to work in ionic 2 project

Tags: angular, ionic2

I had previously attempted to use virtual scroll for an array of cards that will have a varying amount of items. Virtual scroll wouldn't work with my cards and it was suggested I try `ng-template` which kept giving me an error in the terminal that said this :

> Error: Template parse errors:  [01:38:47]  'ng-template' is not a
>   known element:  [01:38:47]  1. If 'ng-template' is an Angular
>   component, then verify that it is part of this module.  [01:38:47]  2.
>   If 'ng-template' is a Web Component then add "CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA"
>   to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this

The other solutions I've tried to get virtual scroll to work have left me with a blank, white, unrendered page, which is strange because you'd think if there was an error the terminal would have told me and the build would fail. I want to try to figure out how to make `ng-template` work for me. Googling hasn't turned up sufficient examples.
This is how I was originally using `virtualScroll`, which is the wrong way to do it. I've tried swapping in div and list elements to put the `virtualScroll` property on and I get the same result of a blank page.

**HTML**

```
<ion-content id="content">
   <ion-card id="card" *ngFor="let event of listOfEvents 
     [virtualScroll]="listOfEvents">          
     <ion-item *virtualItem="let event"> 
       <ion-row>
         <ion-col>
           <span class="showDetails">Guests Needed:</span> {{event.guests}}
         </ion-col>
         <ion-col>
           <span class="showDetails">Cover:</span> {{event.coverCharge}}
         </ion-col>
         <ion-col>
           <span class="showDetails">Drink Min:</span>{{event.drinkMin}
         </ion-col>   
       </ion-row> 
    </ion-item>
  </ion-card>   
</ion-content>
```

Comment: On which version of angular are you?

Comment: @masterfan I'm using angular 2 and ionic 2..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular4 has renamed the ***template*** component to ***ng-template***. And there is also a possibility that you are getting this error as you're still using angular2 but also depend on some package which depends on angular4.

Just run

> npm update

to update to Angular 4 and you should be fine.

Comment: neither npm update nor npm install did anything in my terminal window. Nothing that you would expect from an update or install. It's like I didn't make the command at all..

Comment: Make sure that you have node.js installed. If you don't you will have to install it first. You can find some tutorials on how to install nodejs and npm. And also make sure that you are located in the project root folder while typing npm update.

Comment: It's giving me errors related to package.json. I can't get around this and am going to have to take a different route completely.  I can't believe it's this much hassle just to use a new tag. I'm going to figure out some other way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

The `<ng-template>` element has been introduced in the angular version [4.0.0-rc.1](https://github.com/angular/angular/compare/4.0.0-beta.8...4.0.0-rc.1). You should either update to the latest angular version (advised), or use the `<template>` tag